# Can't heroku run rake db migrate through my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

it is my first time to encounter such error(s):

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8524
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `initialize'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `open'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `block in start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:113:in `rendezvous_session'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:100:in `run_attached'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku run rake db:migrate --app oppcis
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.35.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

I've been out for awhile in using heroku... and after the big comeback, I encountered this error.

I am outdated already in terms of present Heroku news.

I hope somebody could give me a suggestion, solution or issues involved.

Thanks.

EDIT:

The logs says...

```
2013-02-15T08:38:00+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by ssalamat.peg@gmail.com
2013-02-15T08:38:03+00:00 heroku[run.6510]: Awaiting client
2013-02-15T08:38:03+00:00 heroku[run.6510]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-02-15T08:38:04+00:00 heroku[run.6510]: State changed from starting to up
2013-02-15T08:38:33+00:00 heroku[run.6510]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2013-02-15T08:38:34+00:00 heroku[run.6510]: Process exited with status 128
2013-02-15T08:38:34+00:00 heroku[run.6510]: State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: Try running `heroku logs`

Comment: edit: I included the logs above.

Comment: Strange... looks like it's just hangs up. Tried running migration with trace?

Comment: And try running `heroku restart` and then the migration again

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to run it in the "background"

```
 heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

You can also try [heroku troubleshooting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#troubleshooting), as it appears to be a connection problem.

```
heroku run rails console
telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000
```

If it doesn't work, you probably have a firewall blocking your connection to heroku.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would not just copy paste your solution but please let me know what had happened. :D because I want to learn from it also. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#running-tasks-in-background) is the explanation for `run:detached`. Depending on the network, you might face connection problems between your pc and heroku. I don't really know the reason, but these procedures will restore that link. I face this problem a lot when I am in one specific network...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i know why.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This solved my problem