# Heroku with ruby on rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mongoid, mlab

I am working on a project in ROR with Mongoid. The app is working fine when running rails offline server but when I deploy it on Heroku it is throwing me this error

```
2016-02-03T16:34:08.405268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-02-03T16:34:08.394021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-02-03T16:35:22.597553+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by vikkycorner@gmail.com
2016-02-03T16:35:26.533751+00:00 heroku[run.9627]: Awaiting client
2016-02-03T16:35:26.926674+00:00 heroku[run.9627]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-03T16:35:56.536107+00:00 heroku[run.9627]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2016-02-03T16:35:57.348246+00:00 heroku[run.9627]: State changed from up to complete
2016-02-03T16:35:57.337946+00:00 heroku[run.9627]: Process exited with status 128
2016-02-03T16:38:37.531037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/user/all" host=attendmare.herokuapp.com request_id=2d492460-a6cd-44f1-8c72-67b84e92e4e6 fwd="198.7.58.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byte
```

I am not using ActiveRecords but using Mongoid so please suggest me any solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thats not very much to work from - surely the stack trace has something more to go on.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason cause app crash in heroku for example heroku server missing some require gem in your app.
use
$ heroku logs --tail
to view exactly what happen in heroku server.

Comment: I have posted the logs output above but I am unable to understand the output

Comment: this link may help you :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892200/cant-heroku-run-rake-db-migrate-through-my-app