# "heroku run rake db:migrate" command returns ETIMEDOUT error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, rake, dbmigrate

Any ideas why I might be getting the below error message?

```
$ git push heroku master                                                                                                                            
Everything up-to-date                                                                                                                               
$ heroku run rake db:migrate                                                                                                                        
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ agile-retreat-87004... !                                                                                               
▸    ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't heroku run rake db migrate through my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892200/cant-heroku-run-rake-db-migrate-through-my-app)

Answer (score 7):

Try to run in the background. Example:

```
heroku run:detached rake --app app-name db:migrate
```